# How to calculate SURF points for ALL the points in an image using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I need to calculate SURF features of a single specific point in the image using OpenCV.
I am using *SurfDescriptorExtractor* to extract surf features, but it takes an array of *keypoint* as the arguemenet, which in turn was calculated by *SurfFeatureDetector*. Is there any way to use *SurfDescriptorExtractor* to calculate SURF feature of a single point?

Answer (score 0):

Use `push_back()` function to fill the `std::vector` of `cv::Keypoint`.
In your case, this array contains only one element.
You can run `compute` function from class `SurfDescriptorExtractor` on this array with :

```
void compute( const cv::Mat& image, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints, cv::Mat& descriptors ) const;
```

Note that: Row i is the descriptor for keypoint i.